# Android - how can I replicate the Gmail app's settings screen?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a settings screen for an app and I like the Gmail app's settings screens. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

It looks/behaves like a custom list of some sort.
The left side looks like a TwoLineListItem (or just a large TextView and small TextView).
The right side is either a checkbox, a blank, or a downward arrow (like ExpandableListView) to indicate you should press it. (ex: when you press the Signature item, a dialog appears so you can input a signature).

I think one tricky part of this is that the entire list item is a "button", meaning you don't have to press directly on the checkbox to check it, you can press anywhere on the list item.

For example, section 5.2 of this tutorial http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html requires you tap exactly on the checkbox rather than on the entire list item.

Anyone have any ideas on how this is done?

Comment: the link for the screenshot you provided is down

Comment: Should be fixed, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the 'normal' listView.

That UI was built with the [PreferenceActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html)

Always use the `PreferenceActivity` to display settings for your application.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can easily define an [OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) with the [setOnitemClickListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29) method of the ListView. The Listener is called whenever a list item is touched. In the Listener you can either show the dropdown menu or set the Checkbox to 'checked' with the `setChecked(boolean checked)` method of the Checkbox.